# How can I pass a Defined quad number (8 BYTES) as a parameters to a subprogram in 32 bit NASM assembly

Tags: assembly, stack, parameter-passing, nasm, 32bit-64bit

I am using 32-bit NASM assembly and was wondering if there is a way to pass a defined quad number (8bytes) as a parameter to a subprogram in Nasm 32-bit assembly. I know that the stack in 32bit assembly is organized to accept defined double words (4 bytes). So I am wondering if this is even possible to do.

Example code:

```
section .data 
x: dq 10 ;Defining x as a 8 byte number

section .bss 

section .text 
global asm_main

asm_main:
enter 0,0 ;Creating stack frame

push QWORD[x] ;pushing x as a parameter for the test subprogram
call test ;Calling the subprogram
add esp,8 ;Deallocating memory used by parameter 

leave
ret
```

But when I run the code I get an error saying that `(push QWORD[x])`:

> instruction not supported in 32-bit mode

Comment: push each dword separately, or copy it via an XMM register with `movq` load/store.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to push each dword separately

Comment: @John A QWORD can be seen as two DWORDs.  So first push the high DWORD and then the low one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to push each dword separately

```
push dword [x+4]    ; high half first
push dword [x]      ; then low half
```

Or you can do a 64-bit copy via an XMM register with `movq` load/store.  x87 `fild` / `fistp` is probably not worth using, but `movq` is if SSE2 is available.

BTW, avoid the `enter` instruction.  It's *very* slow.  Use `push ebp` / `mov ebp,esp` like compilers do.  (And for the record, you could have answered your own question by looking at compiler output for a function that calls another function, like `void foo(int64_t *p) { bar(*p); }`.  https://godbolt.org/z/0rUx-M